# Gradle latest release version of dependency within range

Tags: groovy, gradle, dependency-injection, version, build.gradle

I'm relatively new to Gradle and have been trying to figure out how to set certain dependencies in my build.gradle file to download the latest release version restricted to a certain major version.

I understand that latest.release is able to retrieve the latest release version, but haven't seen any way that this can be restricted to a particular major version. I also understand that using 15.+ or [15.0, 16.0) would allow you to find the latest version with a major version of 15, release or SNAPSHOT, for a particular dependency. However, I want to be able to download the latest release version of a particular dependency within a specified range, ignoring any SNAPSHOT versions.

Would anyone have any suggestions on how to do this?

Thanks

Clarifications:
Apparently this is not too difficult in the case in which snapshots and releases are in different repositories. However, in this case, I believe the snapshots and releases are in the same repository.
I am also using gradle 1.8

Comment: I think that you can use [15,0 , 16,0 ) without any problem because the usually the snapshot repository is different from the release repository.

Comment: In this case, I think we have both snapshots and releases in the same repository. Do you know any workarounds for this?

Comment: I don't know any method to exclude a version in this case.